# how to get Activity associated with a contact?

Tags: relationships

i want to get activities associated with a Contact..how it can be done..as per my knowledge there is no any relationship between activity and contact..so how can i acheive this please do reply

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by Activity? Is that activity History?

Comment: ya for activity history Vignex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce provides the standard relationship between Contacts and Activity History. You can get the data from the below SOQL Query.

```
Select Id,CONTACT_FIELDS(Select Id,WhoId, WhatId, Subject, IsTask, ActivityDate, OwnerId, Status,OTHER_FIELDS From ActivityHistories) From Contact c
```

You will also have details from the **Events and Tasks** child relationship of Contacts